# Managing Modules in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [Angular js](https://angularjs.org/) for my client side application.

#### Que:1

My folder structure is like :

```
Main
--Client
----app.js
----index.html
----Modules
------Module Name
--------module_name.js
--Server
```

I want to access Module Name.

I have tried using `Main/Client/Module Name` but I didn't get anything.

Which is proper way to get this?

#### Que:2

How can I add all `js` of `Modules` in `index.html`

I have to add all `js` of `modules` and its `controllers` in `index.html` manually.

Is there any way to add `js` automatically when `module` is called?

Comment: here you go http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home

Comment: Does you server point on Client as the static libarary?

Comment: I want Proper routing mechanism for modules.

Comment: you are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

for question 1: you should better use absolute paths, /Main/Client/Module_Name

and for question 2: you should use grunt or a similar task manager to arrange those stuff for you. you can write a merge command that will merge all js files under Module to a single js file and add that file in index.html